# How to learn tensorflow2.0 quickly and efficiently?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have mastered the python3 foundation as well as the basic models and algorithms of some neural networks, but I don’t know how to learn tensorflow2.0 package quickly, it’s so messy and lack logic to me to only read the official document. What can I do for systematic learning? Is there any good course video or book for tensorflow2.0. Please recommend it to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are many courses available in Udemy. Explore and enroll it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a better question for Quora than StackOverflow. In fact, here is more-or-less the same question on Quora: "[What is the most efficient way to learn TensorFlow?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-learn-TensorFlow)". (StackOverflow tends to be less subjective and more technical in nature than general advice.)

The advice I *would* give though is to try and "do" rather than just learn.

Think of a basic categorization task and do it. Then think about it and your results and try to imagine:

1. What are the strengths of your approach?
2. What are the weakenesses to your approach?

By using TensorFlow, you will develop a deeper understanding of what it does. And you will gain real-world experience working with it.